# Как хранить данные используя sheredpreference?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-shared-preferences

Доброе время суток. Мне бы хотелось узнать, как сохранять значение данных используя sheredpreference.
Можете ли вы подать пример, что бы по входу в приложение в первый, была на экране цифра 0, также, что бы было 2 кнопки, которая добавляет значение на 1 и 2 - убавляет значение на 1. Я пересмотрел документации везде, НО, там сохранение данных с текстового поля, а не по нажатию кнопок, не подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот самый простой пример:

```
// Сохранение
public static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "my_settings";

SharedPreferences sPref;
String name = "John"; 

sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor ed = sPref.edit();
ed.putString(PREFERENCES_NAME, name);
ed.commit();

//Чтение
String savedName = sPref.getString(PREFERENCES_NAME, "");
```